# Can't consume context in my mutation resolver, request object passed instead Apollo Server v4

Tags: typescript, express, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I am trying to pass the pubsub to resolvers. I am able to pass pubsub to subscription 'subscribe' functions via the useServer function, and as far as I can tell from research the expressMiddleware context should be passed to all resolvers, but when logging it out I'm just getting the request object.

index.ts

```
const express = require('express')
import router from './routes/index'
import cors from 'cors'
import { graphqlHTTP } from 'express-graphql'
import { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql'
import http from 'http'
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server'
import { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } from '@apollo/server/plugin/drainHttpServer'
import mongoose, { RootQuerySelector } from 'mongoose'
import * as mutations from './graphql/mutations'
import * as queries from './graphql/queries'
import { newMessages } from './graphql/subscriptions/newMessages'
import { PubSub } from 'graphql-subscriptions'
import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws'
import { useServer } from 'graphql-ws/lib/use/ws'
import { expressMiddleware } from '@apollo/server/express4'

type AppContext = {
  token?: string
}

const RootQueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  description: 'Root Query',
  fields: () => queries
})

const RootMutationType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Mutation',
  description: 'Root Mutation',
  fields: () => mutations
})

const RootSubscriptionType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Subscription',
  description: 'Root Subscription',
  fields: () => ({
    newMessages
  })
})

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: RootQueryType,
  mutation: RootMutationType,
  subscription: RootSubscriptionType
})

const startServer = async () => {
  const app = express()
  app.use(cors())
  app.use(router)

  const pubsub = new PubSub()

  const httpServer = http.createServer(app)

  const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({ server: httpServer })

  const serverCleanup = useServer(
    {
      schema,
      context: async (ctx, msg, args) => {
        return {
          pubsub
        }
      },
      onConnect: () => ({ pubsub })
    },
    wsServer
  )

  const server = new ApolloServer<AppContext>({
    schema,
    csrfPrevention: true,
    cache: 'bounded',
    plugins: [
      ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),
      {
        async serverWillStart () {
          return {
            async drainServer () {
              await serverCleanup.dispose()
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  })

  await server.start()

  app.use(
    '/graphql',
    graphqlHTTP({
      schema,
      graphiql: true
    }),
    express.json(),
    expressMiddleware(server, {
      context: async () => ({ pubsub })
    })
  )

  const url = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_USERNAME}:${process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@${process.env.MONGO_URL}/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
  mongoose.connect(url)
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    const listener = httpServer.listen(
      {
        port:
          process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
            ? process.env.PORT || 80
            : process.env.DEV_PORT || 8080
      },
      (res: void) => resolve(res)
    )
  })
  console.log(
    `get poppin' at ${
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        ? process.env.PORT || 80
        : process.env.DEV_PORT || 8080
    } /graphql`
  )
}

startServer()
```

postMessage.js

```
import { GraphQLString } from 'graphql'
import { MessageGQL } from '../../../types/gqlOutputTypes/Message'
import { MessageGroup } from '../../schema/Message'
import { Message } from '../../../types/tsTypes/Message'
import { PubSub } from 'graphql-subscriptions'
import { MessageGQLInput } from '../../../types/gqlInputTypes/MessageGQLInput'
import { MessageGroupType } from '../../types/MessageGroupType'

type NewMessage = {
  id: string
  message: Message
}

export const postMessage = {
  type: MessageGroupType,
  description: 'Add a message to a group',
  args: {
    id: { type: GraphQLString },
    message: { type: MessageGQLInput }
  },
  resolve: async (
    _parent: undefined,
    args: NewMessage,
    context: { pubsub: PubSub }
  ) => {
    const { id, message } = args
    const messageGroup = await MessageGroup.findById(id)
    messageGroup.messages.push(message)
    console.log(context)
    // pubsub.publish('MESSAGE_SENT', {
    //   messageSent: messageGroup.messages
    // }),
    messageGroup.save()

    return messageGroup
  }
}
```

console.log is logging request object.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "trvlr-be",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.12.1",
    "npm": "8.19.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "npx tsc",
    "compile": "tsc -p .",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npx tsc --watch\" \"nodemon -q dist/index.js\"",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "deploy": "git push heroku main",
    "codegen": "graphql-codegen --config codegen.ts"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.8.7",
    "@apollo/server": "^4.9.5",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
    "@types/node-fetch": "^2.6.2",
    "apollo-server": "^3.12.0",
    "apollo-server-core": "^3.11.1",
    "apollo-server-express": "^3.11.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-graphql": "^0.12.0",
    "firebase": "^9.14.0",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "graphql-subscriptions": "^2.0.0",
    "graphql-ws": "^5.14.2",
    "mongoose": "^6.7.3",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.7",
    "pusher": "^5.1.3",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "ws": "^8.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "5.0.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/introspection": "4.0.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "4.0.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-mongodb": "2.4.6",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-resolvers": "4.0.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "@types/google.maps": "^3.52.6",
    "@types/react-native-maps": "^0.24.2",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "concurrently": "^7.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "react-native-debugger": "^1.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3"
  }
}
```

I have tried using the 3rd, 4th and 5th arguments, I have tried changing the structure of my server and I have tried using the context field of the Apolloserver object, the useServer function and the express Middleware function.